Expo - Execution failed for task ':expo-in-app-purchases:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'
I have problem when tying to build android apk:
expo: 51.0.6
react-native: 0.74.1
expo-in-app-purchases: ^14.5.0
app.json:
{ "expo": { "name": "", "slug": "", "version": "1.11.0", "orientation": "portrait", "icon": "./assets/icon.png", "scheme": "", "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic", "splash": { "image": "./assets/splash.png", "resizeMode": "contain", "backgroundColor": "#000" }, "ios": { "supportsTablet": true, "bundleIdentifier": "com.mimsteri.mimsteri" }, "android": { "versionCode": 11, "adaptiveIcon": { "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png", "backgroundColor": "#ffffff" }, "package": "com.mimsteri.mimsteri" } "extra": { "eas": { "projectId": "" } }, "plugins": [ [ "expo-build-properties", { "android": { "minSdkVersion": 30 } } ], "expo-font", "expo-localization" ] } }
`
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo-in-app-purchases:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.


Try:


Run with --info option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
BUILD FAILED in 6m 38s
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
703 actionable tasks: 702 executed, 1 up-to-date
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
`

How can I fix this problem?

Did you find any solution?
I'm having the same issue

I found what causes the problem.
As we can read from this link the expo-in-app-purchases module is deprecated:
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v49.0.0/sdk/in-app-purchases/
Expo itself recommends using the revenue cat module:
react-native-purchases

I personally had installed it by accident at first and hadn't removed it. Even if you don't use it, it is still processed by EAS.
The solution then is to remove it from the packages by running:
npm uninstall expo-in-app-purchases

